# How to run several test files in phpunit?

Tags: phpunit

I have some tests written in several files: `tests/ApiTest.php`, `tests/UtilsTest.php`. Also I have `tests/bootstrap.php` with some includes and `tests/phpunit.xml`

```
<phpunit
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.5/phpunit.xsd"
    backupGlobals="false"
    backupStaticAttributes="false"
    bootstrap="bootstrap.php"
    cacheTokens="false"
    colors="true"
    convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
    forceCoversAnnotation="false"
    mapTestClassNameToCoveredClassName="false"
    processIsolation="false"
    stopOnError="false"
    stopOnFailure="false"
    stopOnIncomplete="false"
    stopOnSkipped="false"
    stopOnRisky="false"
    verbose="false">
</phpunit>
```

If I type `phpunit -c tests/phpunit.xml tests/ApiTest.php`, everything works. Now I want to run tests for all files in tests folder that end up with 'Test.php'. What should I type? Or should I add some suite?

If I type `phpunit -c tests/phpunit.xml tests` there's an empty output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, the test class name has to match its file name, so in `tests/ApiTest.php` has to exist `class ApiTest`.